# Parsing an array of objects with special characters

Tags: javascript

How do I parse a particular object value in an array of objects, object attribute having special characters:

```
var mycars = new Array();

var obj = {"x-h": "4", "y": "1"};

mycars.push(obj);

document.write(mycars[0].a-h + "<br>");
```

Comment: You would do well to include some description in the body of your problem, and not just in your title

Answer (score 1):

Access the property as follows (using quotes):

```
document.write(mycars[0]["x-h"] + "");
```

Also note that you were using "a-h" instead of "x-h".

Answer (score 0):

Values can be retrieved from an object using brackets [ ] .

If your string expression **is a legal JavaScript name** and not a
reserved word, then the "." notation can be used instead.

"x-h" is not a legal Javascript name. Instead you can use x_h , then you can use the "." notation access directly:

```
document.write(mycars[0].x_h + "");
```

Comment: *"If your string expression is a legal JavaScript name and not a reserved word, then the "." notation can be used instead."* You can even use the dot notation if the property name is a reserved word. Example: `var x = {if: 42}; alert(x.if);`. The problem is that some (especially older) browsers will have a problem with that.

Comment: Yes, you are right Felix, however it is not a good practice.